# php pdo weird row results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have 3 tables.

```
PK table
- company

FK table
- staff
- machines

Table Data:

Company:
ID | NAME
1  | FLY RESORTS

Staff:
ID(fk) | NAME
1      | John Doe
1      | Johny Doe

Machines:
ID(fk) | NAME
1      | Bulldozer
1      | Helicopter
1      | Lorry
```

I wrote PDO select count codes :

```
    $keyword = "%" . $_GET["keyword"] . "%" ;


    $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM `company` INNER JOIN staff ON staff.ID = company.ID INNER JOIN machines ON machines.ID = company.ID WHERE (comp.name like '$keyword' or machines.name like '$keyword' or staff.name like '$keyword')"; 
    $result = $conn->prepare($sql); 
    $result->execute(); 
    $numrows = $result->fetchColumn();
```

When I set the `$keyword` to `'fly'`, it returns multiple results counts/rows with same company name.

Is there any problem with my code? Thanks

Comment: Why do you think it's PDO? did you try this query in mysql directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becuse you join, you will get the same company repeated as many times at it is linked to a staff member or a machine. If you just want to count companies, you can use

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT company.ID) FROM ...
```

Comment: Will the keywords from other tables such as machine will be searched if I use this?

Comment: What if I need all the fields from the company table? (If company have more than 10 fields). Do I have to list all columns in the distinct?

Answer (score 1):

That is the way joins works.

Basically you will multiply the number of rows on each table you join so in your case 1*2*3.

You can investigate how your result looks before applying the WHERE statement on this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0eb82/3) I made.

Comment: Thanks :). Didn't thought about this before